# Endomorphisms of a quiver

Tags: representation-theory, quiver

I know that when $k$ is algebraically closed any indecomposable representation of a quiver over $k$ has endomorphism ring isomorphic to $k$ (this is because by Schur's lemma it is a division algebra).

If $k$ is not assumed to be algebraically closed, could you please give me examples (as many as you can!) of indecomposable quivers that possess representations with endomorphisms algebra that are not commutative?

I do not have many examples of interesting indecomposable representations: I tried those of the $A$ and $D$ type quivers but of course these don't work, and I also tried those of the Jordan quiver (1 vertex, 1 loop).

Comment: I presume "indecomposable quivers that possess representations" is a typo for "quivers that possess indecomposable representations"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not true that the endomorphism ring of an indecomposable representation is a division ring, even over an algebraically closed field. Schur's lemma only applies to irreducible representations.

But for an arbitrary field $k$ there are indecomposable representations with any local finite dimensional $k$-algebra as endomorphism ring.

You won't find (finite dimensional, at least) representations of the Jordan quiver with noncommutative endomorphism rings, since its path algebra is $k[t]$, and by the classification of finitely generated modules for a PID, every indecomposable module is of the form $k[t]/I$ for some ideal, whose endomorphism algebra is $k[t]/I$ and hence commutative.

Here's one way of getting any finite dimensional algebra $A$ over $k$ as the endomorphism ring of some representation.

Let $\{a_1,\dots,a_n\}$ be a set of $k$-algebra generators of $A$. Take the quiver with one vertex and $n$ loops, and the representation with $A$, considered as a vector space over $k$, at the unique vertex, with the loops acting by right multiplication by $a_1,\dots,a_n$.

Or for a quiver with no directed cycles, take the quiver with two vertices and $n+1$ arrows from the first vertex to the second vertex, and the representation with $A$ at both vertices, with the arrows acting by right multiplication by $1,a_1,\dots,a_n$.

If $A$ is a local algebra, then both these examples will be indecomposable. If $A$ is a division ring then the first one will even be irreducible.

Comment: So your method works also if $D$ is an arbitrary finite-dimensional algebra over $k$ right (the representation won't be indecomposable then)?

Comment: @Hypaus Actually, I misread the question. It's not true that the endomorphism ring of an indecomposable representation must be a division ring (Schur's lemma only applies to irreducible representations). I'll edit my answer. But yes, my construction shows that any finite dimensional algebra is the endomorphism ring of a representation of some quiver.